# Getting form field font information in itext7

Tags: itext7

I am parsing a PDF document using itext7. I have fetched all the form fields from the document using AcroForm, but I am unable to get font associated with the field using GetFont method. I also tried to parse /DA dictionary but it returns as a PDFString. Is there any way around to get font information or I have to parse /DA dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Actually iText 7 does have a method to determine form field font information, it's needed for generating form field appearances after all: `PdfFormField.getFontAndSize(PdfDictionary)`.

Unfortunately this method is `protected`, so one has to cheat a bit to access it, e.g. one can derive one's own form field class from it and make the method public therein:

```java
class PdfFormFieldExt extends PdfFormField {
    public PdfFormFieldExt(PdfDictionary pdfObject) {
        super(pdfObject);
    }

    public Object[] getFontAndSize(PdfDictionary asNormal) throws IOException {
        return super.getFontAndSize(asNormal);
    }
}
```

*(from test class [DetermineFormFieldFonts](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/DetermineFormFieldFonts.java#L57))*

Using this class we can extract font information like this:

```java
try (   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(PDF_SOURCE);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader)    ) {
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
    for (Entry<String, PdfFormField> entry : form.getFormFields().entrySet()) {
        String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        PdfFormField field = entry.getValue();
        System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", fieldName, field.getFont());

        PdfFormFieldExt extField = new PdfFormFieldExt(field.getPdfObject());
        Object[] fontAndSize = extField.getFontAndSize(field.getWidgets().get(0).getNormalAppearanceObject());
        PdfFont font = (PdfFont) fontAndSize[0];
        Float size = (Float) fontAndSize[1];
        PdfName resourceName = (PdfName) fontAndSize[2];
        System.out.printf("%s - %s - %s - %s\n", Strings.repeat(" ", fieldName.length()),
                font.getFontProgram().getFontNames(), size, resourceName);
    }
}
```

*([DetermineFormFieldFonts](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/DetermineFormFieldFonts.java#L36) test `test`)*

Applied to [this sample document](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/TextFieldsWithFonts.pdf) with some text fields, one gets:

```
TextAdobeThai - null
              - AdobeThai-Regular - 12.0 - /AdobeThai-Regular
TextArial - null
          - Arial - 12.0 - /Arial
TextHelvetica - null
              - Helvetica - 12.0 - /Helv
TextWingdings - null
              - Wingdings - 12.0 - /Wingdings
```

As you can see, while `PdfFormField.getFont()` always returns `null`, `PdfFormField.getFontAndSize(PdfDictionary)` returns sensible information.

---

*<sub>Tested using the current iText for Java development branch, 7.1.5-SNAPSHOT</sub>*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but In Itext while parsing the font information in c#, the /DA dictionary contains font names in half. For Example if font is set to Helvetica or Courier then in itext7 it contains text like Helv or Cour which is not further translated in font families.
Is there any way to get the full font family name?

Comment: @MuddassirAwan Yes, read my answer. In the example result the text field "TextHelvetica" in its **DA** uses the name **Helv** but the code resolves it to "Helvetica".