# How to get font color from acroform?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I using `itext7` and I need to get `font color` from acroform in the pdfformfield. 
I didn't find this property in `PdfFont`.
How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting form field font information in itext7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455849/getting-form-field-font-information-in-itext7)

Comment: @AdilOoze no in that case no font color information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text color from the form field default appearance can be retrieved using

```
Color textColor = field.getColor();
```

for a `PdfFormField field`.

Please beware, though:

- iText 7 only extracts text colors set using one of the operators **g**, **rg**, and **k** which are the convenience operators for setting **DeviceGray**, **DeviceRGB**, and **DeviceCMYK** nonstroking colors respectively. If the color is selected using a different operator or there is no color setting operator at all, `null` will be returned.

  *I've not yet observed a PDF with form field default appearances using other color setting operators. In my experience, therefore, that implementation is sufficient.*
- If the field is a rich text field, the default style string may overrule anything in the default appearances, so the color retrieved using `getColor()` may be incorrect.

  *In this situation, though, a user filling in the field is free to use different colors. Thus, in this case an attempt to retrieve "the text color of the field" is questionable anyways.*
- A PDF processor or JavaScript code in PDFs can ignore or override the default appearance color. Thus, you never can be sure that the color returned here actually is the color a user will eventually perceive the text color as.

Comment: the ```PdfFormField``` doesn't have ```getColor()``` method. I using ```itext 7.0.4``` version.

Comment: @John *"the PdfFormField doesn't have getColor() method"* - it does, it has been added about 8 months ago. *"I using itext 7.0.4 version"* - That you are using such an old version (more than two years old), is an information you should have added to your question.

Comment: as per @mkl comment, this method was added in version 7.1.6 (7.1.9 will be out December 2nd 2019). It is a pretty smooth upgrade between 7.0 and 7.1, so I would strongly encourage you to do it.